# Firebase won't verify 'www' with custom domain

Tags: firebase, dns, firebase-hosting, namecheap

I'm hosting a website with Firebase. I was able to verify my custom domain without any issues. However, I noticed that when visiting the site with 'www' I was getting either a 404 error or an insecure warning.

When I try to add the domain with www to Firebase I'm not able to get if verified. I noticed the site verification string for adding the new domain (with www) is the same as the one I had to add to connect the original domain (without www).

I also tried adding a CNAME record with host www and value of piccy.app. Finally I tried to copy the existing A record and change the host from @ to www.

What am I doing wrong here?

This is the message I'm getting in the console:

[image: Error message in console]

Here's the Namecheap setup:

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: DNS servers are public. There is no need to hide that information. The TXT record in your question does not exist at your domain's authoritative name server. Are you creating the resource record at the wrong DNS server? How long did you wait after creating the record? Edit your question with more information.

Comment: Just use an `@` character instead of the domain; see more details [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain#common-domain-providers).